# SQL Server Date Logic - Finding the next reminder date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

Given the following database table:

```
StartDate DATETIME  -- day that the reminder period starts
LastReminderDate DATETIME -- the last time the reminder triggered
DayOfMonth INT -- the day of the month to remind the user
Interval INT   -- how often in months to remind the user
```

How can I figure out the next reminder date based on these values? For example:

```
StartDate = '6/1/2011'
LastReminderDate = '6/5/2011'
DayOfMonth = 5 -- remind on the 5th of the month
Interval = 2 -- remind every other month
```

For this particular example, the next reminder date should be 8/5/2011 because it reminds on the 5th of the month every two months. How would I write a function to figure this out?

If LastReminderDate is NULL, then LastReminderDate should be equal to StartDate

UPDATE:

```
StartDate = '6/1/2011'
LastReminderDate = NULL
DayOfMonth = 5
Interval = 2
```

In this case, there was no last reminder date. The first time the reminder would occur would be 6/5/2011. The solutions below seem to be returning 8/5 in this case.

Here are some specific rules:

- The Reminder should always occur on whatever DayOfMonth is. If DayOfMonth would be illegal for the given month then it should be the last day of that month. For example....if DayOfMonth is 31 and the next reminder date would fall on June 31, then it should be June 30th instead.
- The next reminder date should always be based off of the Last Reminder Date plus the Interval. If Last Reminder Date does not match the Day of Month, then it could potentially be more than what the interval was. For example...if Last Reminder was 6/1/2011 and the interval is 2 months, but the reminder is for the 20th of the month, then the next reminder will be 8/20/2011.
- If there is no last reminder date, then use the Start Date instead of last reminder date...but this will use the earliest date in the future. If start date was 6/1/2011 and day of month is 5, then this will be 7/5/2011 since today is 6/22/2011. If Day of Month was 25 then it would be 6/25/2011

Comment: What if the start date is `6/14/2011` and the `DayOfMonth = 7` should it be `7/7/2011` or `6/7/2011` what if the `DayOfMonth = 31` should it assume the first day of the month or the last day or should it blow up? You need to let us know what the rules are rather than just picking input and output values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE
@StartDate AS datetime,  -- day that the reminder period starts
@LastReminderDate AS datetime, -- the last time the reminder triggered
@DayOfMonth AS integer, -- the day of the month to remind the user
@Interval AS integer   -- how often in months to remind the user

SET @StartDate = '6/1/2011'
SET @LastReminderDate = '6/5/2011'
SET @DayOfMonth = 5 -- remind on the 5th of the month
SET @Interval = 2 -- remind every other month

SELECT
CASE
   WHEN @LastReminderDate IS NULL
   THEN
     CASE WHEN Day(@StartDate) <= @DayOfMonth
       THEN DateAdd( month, ((Year( @StartDate ) - 1900) * 12) + Month( @StartDate ) - 1, @DayOfMonth - 1 )
       ELSE DateAdd( month, ((Year( @StartDate ) - 1900) * 12) + Month( @StartDate ) - 0, @DayOfMonth - 1 )
     END
  ELSE DateAdd( month, @Interval, @LastReminderDate )
END
```

The meat of this is the last four lines, the `SELECT CASE ... END` statement. I provided a whole script that lets you plug in different values, and see how the `SELECT CASE ... END` behaves for those test values.

But to just use this on your table, use only the last four lines (and remove the `@` from the front of the names so they match the table's column names).

You could also generalize this so that Interval doesn't have to be months. If your table had an IntervalType column, you could supply that as the first argument to `DateAdd()`.  See the docs but some common intervals are `days`, `months`, `years`, and so on.

EDIT2: Respect DayOfMonth.

Comment: Um, who is down-voting my answer and the other answer provided so far, and why??

Comment: Still doesn't appear to be correct. Now if LastReminder is NULL it is giving 8/1/2011

Comment: Maybe there is a different way to think about it...but basically the calculation is usually easy. You would always be able to add X months to the LastReminder date in order to get the next reminder date. The only problem with this is that when you don't have a Last Reminder Date to go off of, you have to figure out what the first reminder date is going to be. This is why I say use StartDate. LastReminderDate should/will always be the same day of Month as I want. It's just trying to figure out the first time to remind them when this doesn't exist. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I misunderstood the DayOfMonth requirement. Will reconsider based on that.

Comment: AS pointed out below I didn't think about if someone changed the day that then reminder should be. Can't always rely on LastReminderDate + Interval.

Comment: I edited again. If I understand you correctly this will handle NULL LastReminderDate correctly. e.g. When StartDate is 6/5 and DayOfMonth is <=5, then the next remidner will be 6/5. Otherwise it will be 7/5. That's as you wanted, correct?  BTW the code looks more complicated than it would if T-SQL had a `make-date( year, month, day )` function. You can define a UDF like that, as on http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx.

Comment: Yeah I created a CreateDate(Year,month,day) function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the StartDate if there is no LastReminderDate, then you'll want to use COALESCE for that bit of logic: `COALESCE(LastReminderDate, StartDate)`

Now, get to the last of the previous month: `DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(COALESCE(LastReminderDate, StartDate)), COALESCE(LastReminderDate, StartDate))`

Finally, add the months and then get to the date that we need:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, Interval, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(COALESCE(LastReminderDate, StartDate)) + DayOfMonth, COALESCE(LastReminderDate, StartDate)))
```

This will potentially go forward less than two months if the date of the last reminder was on a day of the month after the "DayOfMonth" that's configured for the reminder. You should be able to tweak that depending on what your business logic is in that situation.

Comment: This doesn't work when LastReminderDate is 8/1/2011 - it gives me 10/5/2011 instead of 8/5/2011

Comment: @Dismissle you should probably update your question then because its really unclear why that would be

Comment: That was probably a bad example. See my comment on Greg H's answer. Essentially I will always be able to add the interval to the LastReminderDate. When that does not exist then I need to figure out what the first Reminder Date should be based off of Start Date. If Start Date is 6/1/2011 then it should be 6/5/2011 for the first reminder. If it is 6/6/2011 then it should be 7/5/2011. Make sense?

Comment: That's only if there is no LastReminderDate then? What if the reminder is changed so that instead of the 5th it's now always on the 7th? You then can't just add the interval months to your LastReminderDate. There are a lot of specific business cases that I think you might need to think through.